# Obtaining a code dump from a binary

Tags: gdb, assembly

Is it possible to dump the assembly language code of a binary using GDB?

I tried to use the "l" command but it says **No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.**. I use the file command and it says the load symbol was loaded but when I try the "l" command again I see the same message. All I need is the whole assembly language code from that binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, don't apologize for a question. If you did prior research then you are fine. If you didn't take the time to google it, then do that first.

If you want the assembly of a program, then `gdb` might not be your program, instead try `objdump`; however, if you want to view the assembly **while** debugging use the gdb command `disassemble` once you've stopped at a given frame.

Comment: @SpaceDog Indeed. Beware of the flags; on my phone cannot elaborate more.

Comment: Don't necromance. This thread is over two years old and has an accepted answer. Your comment ads little to no additional info.